# storage size of 'start' isn't known

Tags: c

I have this message `error: storage size of 'start' isn't known` when I compile my program. The error is here:

```
struct _timeb start, finish;
```

I make a header file when I've put declarations and prototypes

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/timeb.h>
#include <time.h>
```

In my .c file, I put

```
#include "image.h"
#include <math.h>
```

Comment: Where is `_timeb` defined?

Comment: Show us the declaration of _timeb.

Comment: Can you create a [short, self-contained, correct example](http://sscce.org)?

Answer (score 3):

This usually indicates that the description of the mentioned struct has not yet been encountered, and so you are trying to create a variable of a type the compiler doesn't yet know about.  Likely you are missing a header:

```
#include <sys/timeb.h>
```

Comment: This only has 12 views and you answers seconds ago.

Comment: @stardust_ Let me just look in my magic "upvote history" and see.

Comment: @Khan Without seeing how these snippets are woven together into a whole, it's difficult to diagnose further.  Please see my above comment on the question.

Comment: The header file `sys/timeb.h` defines `struct timeb` not `struct _timeb`? @Khan which one you are referring to in your example ?

Comment: The problem is, it works perfectly on Windows, not on Linux Ubuntu!

Comment: @Khan On Linux the struct is `timeb`, not `_timeb`.